# Are there any solutions for scaling Mule ESB on clouds (amazon preffered)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, mule, scaling, autoscaling

1)Please recommend to me any cloud analogs of Mule ESB.

2)Are there any solutions for scaling (autoscaling) Mule ESB on clouds (amazon preffered)? (for example if i  will use EC2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CloudHub](https://cloudhub.io) is the de-facto cloud offer for Mule. It doesn't support auto-scaling AFAIK but you can easily control the number of deployed nodes with a simple slider. It also exposes a complete API so you can programmatically control your deployed applications and scale them.